# Combining Kotlin Flows into another Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In an Android app, I have a view where the user sets filtering and grouping criteria for a list of items. They are mutableFlows. A repository function returning a Flow should be triggered whenever one of the date filters change, and the resulting list should be processed with the grouping criteria in the view or viewModel when the grouping criteria is updated or the repository sends updates.

**ViewModel**

```
val dateStart = MutableFlow<LocalDate> = ...;
val dateEnd = MutableFlow<LocalDate> = ...;
val grouping = MutableFlow<OrderGroup> = ...;
```

**Repository**

```
fun filteredList(dateStart: LocalDate, dateEnd: LocalDate): Flow<List<Order>>
```

Finally, a viewModel function should be triggered when the filters and grouping are updated, and return the filtered and grouped final list as a Flow:

**ViewModel**

```
val orderTotalsFlow = dateEnd.flatMapLatest { de ->
    orderItemsRepository.findByDates(dateStart.value, de)
        .map { 
        // implemented the grouping using grouping Flow
    }
}
```

However this won't work because it's not triggered when `grouping` Flow is updated by the user. Also I am not able to use [`Flow#combine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) because it will return a `Flow<Flow<List>>>` which looks not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combine` *together* with `flatMapLatest` is the solution:

```
val orderTotalsFlow = combine(dateStart, dateEnd, grouping) { ds, de, gr ->
    orderItemsRepository.findByDates(ds, de)
        .map {
            // implemented the grouping using gr
        }
}.flatMapLatest { it }
```

`flatMapLatest` just flattens a flow of flows into a single, *flat* flow. That's why `combine` returning a `Flow<Flow<List>>` is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks I'll try! Yes, the input parameters of the repository function are LocaDates, it was an editing mistake, I fix it